# Why is my send_mail() command not working in Django?

Tags: python, django, email

I put the following in my settings.py file.  The email address there is a test one.  I found the email settings from [Webfaction](https://help.webfaction.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=128&nav=0,3)'s site:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.webfaction.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'hekevintran_test'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'testpass'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This is what my file looks like:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(subject='subject',
          message='message',
          from_email='hekevintran_test@webfaction.com',
          recipient_list=['recipient@yahoo.com'],
          fail_silently=False)
```

When I run the above it stalls a long time and then gives me this error:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a Django project on Webfaction right now that is properly sending emails. The only difference between your settings and mine is that I did not specify `EMAIL_PORT` or `EMAIL_USE_TLS`. Try it out without those settings and let Django use the default it has and see if it works.

For reference's sake, [the default settings](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-port) are:

```
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had my port set to 465 and i couldn't figure out why it wouldn't send.

Comment: you rocks my friend, u saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my hosted account at asmallorange.com. There, it was a firewall problem. I would suggest contacting support and ensuring port 465 can get through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I deleted EMAIL_PORT and set EMAIL_USE_TLS = True. Now it is work.